# Are there a finite amount of finite sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I became curious about this and I searched and couldn't find the answer.

Are there a finite amount if finite sets, or are there infinitely many finite sets?

(rearranging the order of the set does not change the set)

Comment: No. Consider $\{n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Each set will be finite for each $n$, but there will be infinitely many of these sets.

Comment: In general, the set of finite subsets of a given infinite set  $A$ has the same cardinality as $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There are an infinite number of finite sets. Consider
$$\begin{align}
\{&1\}, \\
\{&1,2\},\\
\{&1,2,3\}, \\
\;\;&\vdots\\
\{&1,2,3,\dotsc,n\}, \\
\;\;&\vdots\\
\end{align}$$
In this list there is exactly one finite set for every integer. Since there are an infinite number of integers, this is an infinite list of finite sets.